# How to call a function defined in a kernel module from a user space program

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have created one kernel module. within the module i have defined some functions say `function1(int n)` and `function2()`.
There was no error in compiling and inserting the module. What i don't understand is how to call the `function1(n)` and `function2()` from a user space program.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no direct way to do it, you can't link userspace code with the kernel like you do with a library. First, you have to register your function as syscall and then call the syscall with the syscall() function.

See [here](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Implement-Sys-Call-Linux-2.6-i386/)

Also some interface between kernel and user space possible using socket communication see
this [link](http://people.ee.ethz.ch/%7Earkeller/linux/kernel_user_space_howto.html#ss3.3)

And find use full link related to this topic at right side of page.

You can make your driver to react on writes to a /dev/file file or a /proc/file file.

**EDIT**

Form name file my point is device is as file in kernel and you can access via `ioctl()`
the pretty good explanation is http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/lkmpg.html#AEN885

See [Link](http://www.faqs.org/docs/kernel/x571.html)

Comment: u mean that i have add a system call for my module

Comment: @tunu I think writing new system call is bad idea. I not recommended you to do it because the module would only work on custom built kernels.Batter idea is write in file. Have updated answer please see

Comment: write in file ?? i  dont get it

Comment: @tunu i mean each device is represented in the kernel by a file structure.See my link.

Comment: Actually my module is not a device driver ..it is more like a mutex and binary semaphore.

Comment: @tunu I think netlink socket allows you to easily pass arbitrary data structures between user level and kernel level.See already i given you a link in my answer.

Comment: @tunu I think netlink socket is the best option as suggest by Jayesh. Probablby for debug you can try the sys filesystem.

Comment: the netlink socket sounds like its all network stuff .. my module is a synchronization protocol like mutex.